# How to tar.gz *.php, *.txt, *.inc, *.js, *.css, *.php3 files?

Tags: unix, gzip, tar

I want to backup my server, but not bother with images /videos etc.

how can i tar.gz all those types of files i want (basically text files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **find** command to create an input list for most versions of **tar**.

Depending on the flavor of Unix are you using the command syntax may differ. For example on IBM AIX it would be something like this:

```
$ cd /directory/you/want/to/archive
$ find . \( -name '*.php' -o \
            -name '*.txt' -o \
            -name '*.inc' -o \
            -name '*.js' -o \
            -name '*.css' -o \
            -name '*.php3' \) -print > /tmp/input.list
$ tar -c -L/tmp/input.list -f - | gzip -c > /path/to/backup.tar.gz
```

If you have the fancy GNU(/Linux) utils you can do:

```
$ cd /directory/you/want/to/archive
$ find . -regex '.*\.\(php\|txt\|inc\|js\|css\|php3\)' -print > /tmp/input.list
$ tar -c -z -T /tmp/input.list -f /path/to/backup.tar.gz
```

Comment: excellent work you great man!!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `--exclude=PATTERN` from [tar](http://man.cx/tar).

That would be a 'negative enumeration'.
For a 'positive enumeration' you can do this:

```
find . -name "*.php" -o -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.inc" -o -name "*.js" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.php3" -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcvf backup.tar.gz
```

`-print0` and `-0` are used for filenames with spaces on them.

Answer (score 1):

[how to tar may help you](http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-tar-targz-tgz-tarbz2.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `bash4` or `zsh` as your shell, you could also perform this task without resorting to `find`.

First, you need to enable fancy file globbing. In Bash, this can be done like this:

> `shopt -s extglob globstar`

In Zsh, the corresponding command is:

> `setopt extendedglob`

The rest is a piece of cake:

> `tar zcvf archive.tgz /path/to/dir/**/*(*.php|*.txt|*.inc|*.js|*.css|*.php3)`

The `**` is a *recursive wildcard*, which matches all levels of subdirectories. The parenthesis is called a *glob modifier*, and restricts the matches of the preceding `*` wildcard to those that also match one of `*.php`, `*.txt`, etc.